# how to sync cookies android in webview and chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

i have search for this but not found answer in stackoverflow untill now.
My project is create android webview app show mobile version of website.
i know there are no way website can detect the app installed on device or not while running in chrome browser for security.

So I change the useragent of the android app with addtional App's name .. then every time user use the app, website will detect web is running in webview then write cookes " Appname" in device.

from there if user using chrome to browse website will find that cookie, if not found web will show some link help user install the app.

The problems is sysn cookies between my app and chrome look like not work.

following is my activity.java
Thanks for any help !

```
public class XaLuanActivity extends Activity{   
    private static final String tag=XaLuanActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final int CHIASE_MENU=1;
    private static final int THOAT_MENU=2;
    private static final int TAILAI_MENU=3;
    private static final int TROGIUP_MENU=4;
    private static final int DANHGIA_MENU=5;

    private String mainUrl="http://www.xaluan.com/m.php";
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    WebView wbvContent;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.xaluan);
        wbvContent=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbvContent);
        //wbvContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);             
        wbvContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wbvContent.setInitialScale(1);
        wbvContent.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wbvContent.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wbvContent.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wbvContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        wbvContent.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
              startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        wbvContent.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
                wbvContent.getSettings().getUserAgentString() 
                + " "
                + getString(R.string.user_agent_suffix)
        );   // detect useragent and add XLAndroidApp suffix name to the end

        HelloWebViewClient wbvClient=new HelloWebViewClient();
        wbvContent.setWebViewClient(wbvClient);

        if(!isConnectedNetwork(this)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Thông báo")
            .setMessage("Không có kết nối mạng, vui lòng kết nối mạng để sử dụng")
            .setPositiveButton("Thử lại", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    XaLuanActivity.this.finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(XaLuanActivity.this, XaLuanActivity.class));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Thoát", new OnClickListener() {             
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    XaLuanActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
        }else {         
             wbvContent.loadUrl(mainUrl);
             wbvContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)  {
                    if(progress < 100 && mProgressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                       mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if(progress == 100) {
                       mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
                 }
             });
        }  
        isFirstTime();
    }
    public void isFirstTime() {// check if the first time
        try{
            SharedPreferences mPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             boolean firstTime=mPreference.getBoolean("firstTime", true);        
             if(firstTime) {                
                ShortcutIconResource icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, XaLuanActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME", "Xã Luận");
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON_RESOURCE", icon); //can also be ignored too
                intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit=mPreference.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
                edit.commit();
             }     
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag+".isFirstTime", e.toString());
        }             
    }


    private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url != null && (url.startsWith("market://")  || url.indexOf("play.google.com/store/apps/details")!=-1) ) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                //return true;
            } 
            else if(url.endsWith(".apk") || url.indexOf("adsxaluan.apk.vn/download/")!=-1 ) 
            {
                view.getContext().startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url)) );
            }            
            else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                //return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, CHIASE_MENU, 0, "Chia Sẻ").setIcon(R.drawable.share);       
        menu.add(0, TAILAI_MENU, 0, "Tải Lại").setIcon(R.drawable.refresh);
        menu.add(0, DANHGIA_MENU, 0, "Đánh Giá").setIcon(R.drawable.rate);
        menu.add(0, TROGIUP_MENU, 0, "Trợ Giúp").setIcon(R.drawable.about);     
        menu.add(0, THOAT_MENU, 0, "Thoát").setIcon(R.drawable.exit);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CHIASE_MENU: // chia se
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, wbvContent.getTitle());
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, wbvContent.getUrl());                     
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Chia sẻ"));
            break;
        case THOAT_MENU: // chia se 
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case TAILAI_MENU: // chia se    
            wbvContent.reload();
            break;
        case TROGIUP_MENU: // chia se
            Intent intent1=new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case DANHGIA_MENU:
            String url="market://details?id="+getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(wbvContent.canGoBack()) {
                wbvContent.goBack();
                return false;
            }else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Thoát")
                .setMessage("Bạn có muốn thoát khỏi ứng dụng không")
                .setPositiveButton("Có", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        XaLuanActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Không", null)
                .show();
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public static boolean isConnectedNetwork(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but what you want to do is not possible. The cookie jar for your app and Chrome are completely separate and inaccessible to each other for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Is that still valid ?